# python making random combinations of values from two lists

Tags: python, random

I have three lists of values (numbers and letters) and I want to write a program that makes combinations of one of each lists randomly.

I found a code making all possible combinations of values and I thought that might be a good base, but now I don t know how to continue. Who can help me?

Here the code I have

```
import itertools

square = [a, s, d, f, g, h, j, k, l ]
circle = [w, e, r, t, z, u, i, o, p ]
line = [y, x, c, v, b, n, m ]
radiusshape = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]

for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
  for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
    print(subset)
```

Comment: can you please write desire output ? which kind of combination pair you need as output. single/multiple from two list or from all, within list or from any list. please specify

Comment: I want combinations that include one value of each list. for example "awy1" or "stb8"

Comment: then you already got solution from @Martin Broadhurst

Comment: fwiw you are looking for sampling out of a "cartesian product" not a set of "combinations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `random.choice()` function to select a random element from a list, so just use it on all 4 lists:

```
from random import choice

combination = (choice(square), choice(circle), choice(line), choice(radiusshape))
```

Comment: great! it works. Is there a way how I can tell it to do X amount of combinations at once?

Comment: Just use a `for` loop over `range()`, but I think CoryKramer's solution is better.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to draw `k` random samples from your generated [cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
# where k is number of samples to generate
samples = random.sample(itertools.product(square, circle, line, radiusshape), k)
```

For example

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> c = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> random.sample(set(itertools.product(a,b,c)), 5)
[(1, 'c', 'foo'),
 (4, 'c', 'bar'),
 (1, 'd', 'bar'),
 (2, 'a', 'foo'),
 (2, 'd', 'foo')]
```